# Pickle Dictionary not Updating - Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pickle

I am currently trying to have my program update a string in a Pickle dictionary once the user presses a button. Whenever I attempt to update that string though, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Save/Load/Defaults:

```
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = ('#000000')
FOREGROUNDCOLOR = ('#FFFFFF')
default = ('default')
setupcomplete = ('False')


data = {
    'background_color' : BACKGROUNDCOLOR,
    'foreground_color' : FOREGROUNDCOLOR,
    'complete_setup' : setupcomplete,
    'user_name' : default
}

def load():
    print('load')

    with open("./Minetick_Data/datasave", "rb") as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)

def save():
    print('save')

    with open("./Minetick_Data/datasave", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)

def update():
    setupcomplete = 'True'
    save()
```

This is where I attempt to update data['complete_setup']/setupcomplete:

```
class ProgramSetup(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        ProgramSetup.configure(self, background = BACKGROUNDCOLOR)


        titleLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Program Setup", font = TITLE_FONT, background = BACKGROUNDCOLOR, foreground = FOREGROUNDCOLOR)
        finishButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Finish", command = lambda: combine_funcs(update, controller.show_frame(StartPage)))

        titleLabel.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
        finishButton.pack(padx = 10)
```

Whenever I launch the program though, it launches with the defaults (False instead of True)

Comment: Maybe because you're using `'False'` instead of `False`. The first is a string, the second is the boolean value. Same with `True`.

Comment: I'm not running your code, but I think the problem is when you do `data = pickle.load(f)`, this step totally change the value of the first `data` dictionary. I don't even see a proper use of the `data` dictionary on your extract.

Comment: Are you pressing the "Finish" button?

Comment: Yes, I am pushing the 'Finish' button, but it doesn't seem to work. The button loads the next page and runs the Update() function, but doesn't update the dictionary.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've posted do you change `data`, so far as I can see.  Also the call `ProgramSetup.configure` seems odd.  Should this be `self.configure`?

Comment: It works either way with self.configure and ProgramSetup.configure. But even if I use setupcomplete = 'True' and data['complete_setup'], the program still doesn't run properly in the Update function.

Comment: I'll run your code and check it out.  Is this a complete working example you've posted?  No, I see it isn't.  If you'll post a minimal working example, I'll check it out.

Comment: A complete example of my code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/q44Kz3TN

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I do not have enough rep.

Anywho, one issue I think I see is with this:

```
finishButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Finish", command = lambda: combine_funcs(update, controller.show_frame(StartPage)))
```

You're having `finishButton` run a command called `combine_funcs` (which I don't see a function listed for it) that runs the function `update`(which then calls `save`, by the way) and then goes to `StartPage`. As far as I know, tkinter buttons cannot accept multiple arguments natively, so you should move `finishButton`'s actions to a function, which could look like this:

```
def combine_funcs():
    setupcomplete = 'True'
    print('save')
    with open("./Minetick_Data/datasave", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
    controller.show_frame(StartPage)
```

This combines both the `update` and the `save` functions and then returns it to the `StartPage`.
Hopefully I helped some.

Comment: combine_funcs() can be found on my PasteBin link: http://pastebin.com/q44Kz3TN. I've used that function before and it works perfectly fine. I know for a fact that the program runs through both update and then shows the next frame. I am having issues with the dictionaries, nothing else.